# Dynamic SQL columns addition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I have a query something like:

```
SELECT t1, t2, t3
FROM Table
WHERE v1 = 'one' AND v2 ='two' AND v3 = 'three';
```

Now values of `v1`, `v2` and `v3` are from front-end. The user may or may not pass all three values or even he can pass a combination of them, like only `v1` and `v2` or only `v2` and `v3` etc.

My question is how can I pass `v1`, `v2` and `v3` to the query dynamically, as in if the user never gives `v2`, that column itself should not be there.

Hope I made myself clear. Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can show us at the least the framework of your application code which is calling SQL server?  I'm afraid your question is a bit vague as it stands now.

Comment: Build a string, execute the string.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the `v1`, `v2`, and `v3` will have `NULL` values coming from the UI in the event that they do not get passed, then you can try using the `COALESCE()` function:

```
SELECT t1, t2, t3
FROM Table
WHERE COALESCE(v1, 'one') = 'one' AND COALESCE(v2, 'two') ='two' AND
    COALESCE(v3, 'three') = 'three';
```

Now if the user does not pass any of the three columns, the query will effectively ignore them when determining which records to include in your result set.

Comment: hi Tim. i think what Ash means is the column name is dynamic not the value of the column. the user might only want see t1 and t2 so the query should be select t1,t2 from table ... or user want see all of them so it will be select t1,t2,t3 from table. something like that

Comment: @Raffaello.D.Huke His question is vague.  If he doesn't want certain columns, then it is the responsibility of his app layer to create the appropriate query.  My answer gives him a way to _always_ pass _all_ columns, ignoring those which are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods are there in your scenario.

1.From the code (Java Or .Net etc)

The SQL query should concatenate the and clause and condition like v1='ONE' if and only if user selects the option. This can be achieve simply by IF condition.

2.The second method I think efficient.

Handle it with case statement.

```
        DECLARE @V1 VARCHAR(10), @V2 VARCHAR(10), @V3 VARCHAR(10)

        SELECT T1, T2, T3 FROM TABLE_1
        WHERE CASE @V1 WHEN 'A' THEN  'A' ELSE V1 END = @V1
        AND CASE @V2 WHEN  'A' THEN  'A' ELSE V2 END = @V2
        AND CASE @V3 WHEN  'A' THEN  'A' ELSE V3 END = @V3
```

Note: Here you need to pass at least default value like "A" when user not selected anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL. Try like this,

```
DECLARE @v1     VARCHAR(256)='',
        @v2     VARCHAR(256)='',
        @v3     VARCHAR(256)='',
        @cmd    NVARCHAR(max)='',
        @filter NVARCHAR(max)=' where 1=1 '

IF @v1 IS NOT NULL
   AND @v1 <> ''
  BEGIN
      SET @filter+=' and v1=' + @v1
  END

IF @v2 IS NOT NULL
   AND @v2 <> ''
  BEGIN
      SET @filter+=' and v2=' + @v2
  END

IF @v3 IS NOT NULL
   AND @v3 <> ''
  BEGIN
      SET @filter+=' and v3=' + @v3
  END

SET @cmd='SELECT t1, t2, t3
FROM Table' + @filter

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @cmd
```

Comment: Close I think; but the values one, two, three are absent e.g. `SET @filter+=' and one=' + @v1`

Comment: @Used_By_Already: All the values are absent then the final query would be formed like this select t1,t2,t3 from table where 1=1. It returns all the records.

Comment: the variables ARE the column names & you mistake my intention I think. I believe you are close, but not quite there. the values need to be present in your answer. otherwise you have v1 = v1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let parameters be

```
paramV1 VARCHAR(256)=NUll
paramV2 VARCHAR(256)=NUll
paramv3 VARCHAR(256)=NULL
```

Now,

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(256)='%%',
        @v2 VARCHAR(256)='%%',
        @v3 VARCHAR(256)='%%'

if paramV1 is not null
begin
   @v1=paramV1
end

if paramV2 is not null
begin
   @v2=paramV2
end

if paramV3 is not null
begin
    @v3=paramV3
end

SELECT t1, t2, t3
FROM Table
WHERE v1 = @v1 AND v2 =@v2 AND v3 = @v3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
DECLARE @v1 int = 0, @v2 int = null, @v3 int = 0

DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(MAX) = 
    'SELECT ' + REPLACE(
        CASE WHEN @v1 IS NOT NULL THEN 't1,' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN @v2 IS NOT NULL THEN 't2,' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN @v3 IS NOT NULL THEN 't3,' ELSE '' END + '#', ',#', ' ') +
    'FROM Table ' +
    'WHERE ' + REPLACE(
        CASE WHEN @v1 IS NOT NULL THEN ' t1 = ' + cast(@v1 as nvarchar(30)) + ' AND' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN @v2 IS NOT NULL THEN ' t2 = ' + cast(@v2 as nvarchar(30)) + ' AND'ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN @v3 IS NOT NULL THEN ' t3 = ' + cast(@v3 as nvarchar(30)) + ' AND'ELSE '' END + '#', 'AND#', '')

EXEC(@sql);
```

Note: In above querybased on input values of `@v1`, `@v2` and `@v3` your columns will change ;).